# CheckBoxes "stealing" bitmaps from each other

Tags: c#, wpf, resources, styles

I have a WPF-control, which uses some checkboxes with an self defined style.
But I made a mistake in the style, because if I check a second checkbox, the check.png-image is "stolen" from the first one. The first checkboxes property 'IsChecked' is still true, but it dosent show the image anymore. It looks like I can only have the check.png shown once in the control/window. The image is included in the project and build action is 'Resource' and 'do not copy to output directory'.

I made a litte example-window, which has the same behavior:

```
<Window x:Class="CheckStyleRes.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CheckStyleRes"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style TargetType="CheckBox" >
                <Style.Resources>
                    <CornerRadius x:Key="ButtonCornerRadius">3</CornerRadius>
                </Style.Resources>

                <Setter Property="Width" Value="19"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="19"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                            <Border Name="border" BorderThickness="1" Padding="4,2" CornerRadius="3" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <Border.BorderBrush>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                                        <GradientStop Color="LawnGreen" Offset="0"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="DarkGreen" Offset="1"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Border.BorderBrush>
                                <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" ContentSource="Content" Margin="0"/>
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Content">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <Image Margin="0" Stretch="None" Source="/CheckStyleRes;component/CHECK.png" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsHitTestVisible="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" UseLayoutRounding="True"/>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                                    <Setter Property="Content">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <Image Margin="0" Stretch="None" Source="/CheckStyleRes;component/CHECK.png" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsHitTestVisible="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" UseLayoutRounding="True" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>

                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <CheckBox></CheckBox>
            <CheckBox></CheckBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

How do I have to include the image, so that it can be shown more than once.

Thank you.

Comment: A UIElement like the Image in your Style/Trigger Setter can only have a single parent element, and hence only appear once in a visual tree. You may set `x:Shared="False"` on it. Besides that it looks weird that you have a Trigger for IsChecked=false that sets a hidden Image, instead of setting no image at all.

Comment: Thank you for this advice.
I think, the idea of setting the image to Hidden is to save the same space as if it would be shown. (Its not my code btw., I inherited it from a college (~_ö))